# An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll but was not handled in user code

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm pretty new to all of this.

As the title suggests I am getting the following error:

> An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll but was not handled in user code

All I am trying to do to this point is view a list of staff in the index view.

I have a model named staffrep, the code is as follows:

```
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;
 using BookingsModel;

 namespace Bookings.Models
{
    public class staffrep
    {
        private ModelBookings db = new ModelBookings();

        public IEnumerable<BookingsModel.Staff> All()
        {
        return db.Staffs.Where(b => b.Active.Equals(true));
        }
    }
}
```

I then have the staff controller, the code is as follows (I can view staff members if I use the two lines commented out)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using BookingsModel;

namespace Bookings.Controllers
{
    public class StaffController : Controller
    {
        BookingsModel.ModelBookings db = new BookingsModel.ModelBookings();
        // GET: Staff
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            Models.staffrep staffrep = new Models.staffrep();
            var staff_ = staffrep.All();
            return View(staff_);

            //var staff_ = db.Staffs.Where(b => b.Active == true);
            //return View(staff_);

        }
```

The full error I get is:

> An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Unable to create a constant value of type 'System.Object'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.

Code for ModelBookings:

```
namespace BookingsModel
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
    using System.Linq;

    public partial class ModelBookings : DbContext
    {
        public ModelBookings()
            : base("name=ModelBookingsdb")
        {
        }

        public virtual DbSet<Booking> Bookings { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<BookingAttendance> BookingAttendances { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<BookingTime> BookingTimes { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Cost> Costs { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Invoice> Invoices { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<PaymentMethod> PaymentMethods { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Company> Companies { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<CompanyOpeningHour> CompanyOpeningHours { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Industry> Industries { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<CompanyReview> CompanyReviews { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Equiptment> Equiptments { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<EquiptmentType> EquiptmentTypes { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<EquiptmentNeeded> EquiptmentNeededs { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Service> Services { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<ServiceType> ServiceTypes { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Staff> Staffs { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<StaffAccess> StaffAccesses { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<StaffRole> StaffRoles { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<SystemAuthorization> SystemAuthorizations { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<ProductImage> ProductImages { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<ProductSupplier> ProductSuppliers { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Stock> Stocks { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<StockLevel> StockLevels { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<StockType> StockTypes { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Service_Products> Service_Products { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Booking>()
                .HasMany(e => e.BookingAttendances)
                .WithRequired(e => e.Booking)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Booking>()
                .HasMany(e => e.BookingTimes)
                .WithRequired(e => e.Booking)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Booking>()
                .HasMany(e => e.Invoices)
                .WithRequired(e => e.Booking)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Cost>()
                .HasMany(e => e.Invoices)
                .WithRequired(e => e.Cost)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

            modelBuilder.Entity<PaymentMethod>()
                .HasMany(e => e.Invoices)
                .WithRequired(e => e.PaymentMethod)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Company>()
                .HasMany(e => e.Bookings)
                .WithRequired(e => e.Company)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Company>()
                .HasMany(e => e.CompanyOpeningHours)
                .WithRequired(e => e.Company)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Company>()
                .HasMany(e => e.CompanyReviews)
                .WithRequired(e => e.Company)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Company>()
                .HasMany(e => e.Staffs)
                .WithRequired(e => e.Company)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Industry>()
                .HasMany(e => e.Companies)
                .WithRequired(e => e.Industry)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>()
                .HasMany(e => e.Bookings)
                .WithRequired(e => e.Customer)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>()
                .HasMany(e => e.BookingAttendances)
                .WithRequired(e => e.Customer)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>()
                .HasMany(e => e.CompanyReviews)
                .WithRequired(e => e.Customer)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Equiptment>()
                .HasMany(e => e.EquiptmentNeededs)
                .WithRequired(e => e.Equiptment)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

            modelBuilder.Entity<EquiptmentType>()
                .HasMany(e => e.Equiptments)
                .WithRequired(e => e.EquiptmentType)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Service>()
                .HasMany(e => e.Bookings)
                .WithRequired(e => e.Service)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Service>()
                .HasMany(e => e.Costs)
                .WithRequired(e => e.Service)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Service>()
                .HasMany(e => e.EquiptmentNeededs)
                .WithRequired(e => e.Service)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Service>()
                .HasMany(e => e.Service_Products)
                .WithRequired(e => e.Service)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

            modelBuilder.Entity<ServiceType>()
                .HasMany(e => e.Services)
                .WithRequired(e => e.ServiceType)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

            modelBuilder.Entity<StaffRole>()
                .HasMany(e => e.Staffs)
                .WithRequired(e => e.StaffRole)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

            modelBuilder.Entity<StaffRole>()
                .HasMany(e => e.StaffAccesses)
                .WithRequired(e => e.StaffRole)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

            modelBuilder.Entity<SystemAuthorization>()
                .HasMany(e => e.StaffAccesses)
                .WithRequired(e => e.SystemAuthorization)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

            modelBuilder.Entity<ProductImage>()
                .HasMany(e => e.Stocks)
                .WithRequired(e => e.ProductImage)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

            modelBuilder.Entity<ProductSupplier>()
                .HasMany(e => e.Stocks)
                .WithRequired(e => e.ProductSupplier)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Stock>()
                .HasMany(e => e.Service_Products)
                .WithRequired(e => e.Stock)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Stock>()
                .HasMany(e => e.StockLevels)
                .WithRequired(e => e.Stock)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

            modelBuilder.Entity<StockType>()
                .HasMany(e => e.Stocks)
                .WithRequired(e => e.StockType)
                .HasForeignKey(e => e.ProductStockTypeID)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
        }
    }
}
```

The error point to a line of code in the index.cshtml file:

```
<th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
```

Comment: Could you post the code for ModelBookings?  The name does not sound like it is the DataContext which is used for interacting with the database

Comment: @KenTucker I've added that in for you.

Comment: Did the database create ok?

Comment: @KenTucker yes, likeI've said above the code works when I use the two lines commented out.  I've added, deleted and edited current records and it works until I use the code above.

Comment: @OverdueOrange have you tried changing `db.Staffs.Where(b => b.Active.Equals(true));` into `db.Staffs.Where(b => b.Active);`?

Comment: @RMH Just tried that and it not compile. The error points to a line of code in the index view.  Ive now attached that above

Comment: @OverdueOrange what type is the `Active` property on your class? Can you at least try `.Where(b => b.Active == true)` as in your code that has been commented out?

Comment: @RMH yes that has worked, thank you very much,